# Shiny App ! LaTeX Error: File `unicode-math.sty' not found

Tags: shiny, r-markdown, knitr, shinyapps, tinytex

I created a shiny app to generate a downloadable pdf report with knitr and rmarkdown.

I am able to generate the report in Rstudio, but when I attempt to do so from the app, I get this error:

```
2020-04-22T19:40:03.590795+00:00 shinyapps[2124372]: cannot setup TLPDB in /home/shiny/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5604.
2020-04-22T19:40:03.593636+00:00 shinyapps[2124372]: Warning in system2("tlmgr", args, ...) :
2020-04-22T19:40:03.593638+00:00 shinyapps[2124372]:   running command ''tlmgr' search --file --global '/unicode-math.sty'' had status 2
2020-04-22T19:40:03.594869+00:00 shinyapps[2124372]: ! LaTeX Error: File `unicode-math.sty' not found.
2020-04-22T19:40:03.594871+00:00 shinyapps[2124372]: 
2020-04-22T19:40:03.594872+00:00 shinyapps[2124372]: ! Emergency stop.
2020-04-22T19:40:03.594873+00:00 shinyapps[2124372]: <read *> 
2020-04-22T19:40:03.594873+00:00 shinyapps[2124372]: 
2020-04-22T19:40:03.597624+00:00 shinyapps[2124372]: Warning: Error in : LaTeX failed to compile /tmp/RtmpDEOSFT/fileca7f657fa3.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See fileca7f657fa3.log for more info.
2020-04-22T19:40:03.602043+00:00 shinyapps[2124372]:   [No stack trace available]
```

The debugging tips suggested reinstalling tinytex so I tried that. I also downloaded unicode-math.sty individually to my shiny app folder and redeploying, but neither helped. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can we see your code, e.g. on github?

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/jvanzalk/easy-engagement-reports

I just created the repository so it's a little bare bone. Let me know if you need clarification on anything. 

One idea that just came to mind is to create a directory for the missing tex packages like I did for OpenSans. Any idea if that would work? Thanks!

Comment: Just for the record, this was cross-later posted to https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/205.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue and couldn't found the solution. Please use the below solution to resolve this problem.

Go to the folder where your tex packages are installed that would most probably be in C:\Users\vksharma\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\texmf-dist\tex\latex\unicode-math. Copy all the four files i.e., [image]

into your working directory. Then write the following code wherein you have rendered the markdown pdf:

```
      tempsty <- file.path(tempdir(), "unicode-math.sty")
      file.copy("unicode-math.sty", tempsty, overwrite = TRUE)
      tempxesty <- file.path(tempdir(), "unicode-math-xetex.sty")
      file.copy("unicode-math-xetex.sty", tempxesty, overwrite = TRUE)
      tempxesty1 <- file.path(tempdir(), "unicode-math-table.tex")
      file.copy("unicode-math-table.tex", tempxesty, overwrite = TRUE)
      tempxesty2 <- file.path(tempdir(), "unicode-math-luatex.sty")
      file.copy("unicode-math-luatex.sty", tempxesty, overwrite = TRUE)
```

What it does basically is copy these files from your working directory to the temporary directory of the shinyapps server and then while rendering the markdown, it searched for these packages and install them.

Happy Coding!